# locked div columns and remaining width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a 5 column layout, where all columns are full height of browser window.

All but the middle column should be locked/fixed, and not move when scrolling the browser/document.

The middle column will contain the website content and will overflow vertically, so should scroll along "as usual" in the browser.

In addition to that, all but the middle column have a fixed width, and I need the middle column to take up the remaining space (of the parent, 100% of the body width)

One requirement is to not use flexbox or css-grid.

the below code is what I got. Adding column "c" even messes up the full height of all columns and add top/bottom margins. I'm so lost here and would really appreciate some help.

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
.parent{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.parent,.a,.b,.c,.d,.e{
    display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}

.a{
    background-color:#99a4fa;
  width:10%;
}
.b{
    background-color:#5b6cfa;
  width:100px;
}
.c{
    background-color:#3847b8;
  width:20%; /* this should be remaining, not 20% */
}
.d{
    background-color:#1a299c;
  width:100px;
}
.e{
    background-color:#0d1c8d;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">
    a<br/>locked
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    b<br/>locked
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    remaining width
    <br/>
    so all cols take up 100% width
    <Br/>
    of parent
    <br/><br/>
    only div that should scroll vertically with the page
  </div>
  <div class="d">
    d<br/>locked
  </div>
  <div class="e">
    e<br/>locked
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "One requirement is to not use flexbox or css-grid.". That's both curious and annoying. Who says you can't use common, modern layout techniques? Is this some sort of challenge?

Comment: @isherwood I had something similar using flexbox but it didnt play well with a lots of custom javascript code, and getting that to work would be bigger task than trying to get it to work without flex. And css-grid is too new (looking at caniuse.com), hope that answers your question :) and would be grateful for your help if you can..

Comment: You have a Carriage Return (newline) afger each div. Then there will be a gap (a white space) between the columns because you are using display: inline-block

Comment: Thanks, that does answer my question. However, consider: https://css-tricks.com/a-business-case-for-dropping-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

i use position sticky and make the middle column flow with scroll

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
.parent{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.parent,.a,.b,.c,.d,.e{
    display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}

.a{
    background-color:#99a4fa;
  width:10%;
}
.b{
    background-color:#5b6cfa;
  width:100px;
}
.c{
    background-color:#3847b8;
  width:20%; /* this should be remaining, not 20% */
   position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    height:auto;
}
.d{
    background-color:#1a299c;
  width:100px;
}
.e{
    background-color:#0d1c8d;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">
    a<br/>locked
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    b<br/>locked
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    remaining width
    <br/>
    so all cols take up 100% width
    <Br/>
    of parent
    <br/><br/>
    only div that should scroll vertically with the page
  </div>
  <div class="d">
    d<br/>locked
  </div>
  <div class="e">
    e<br/>locked
  </div>
</div>
```

want

Comment: thank you. but A B D E should be locked/sticky. only C scroll. for me, they all scroll now.